# AppleScript to Apple Watch or OS X app to Apple Watch

Tags: xcode, macos, applescript, apple-watch

2 questions.

1. Is it possible to send AppleScript actions to an apple watch ?? Like send a string of text to be displayed on an Apple Watch ?
2. If question one isn't possible is it possible to send information directly from an OS X app to an Apple Watch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not directly. You could send a message to a remote push notification service which the (phone or) watch could receive and display, provided it has registered itself with that service.

   > Apple Watch takes full advantage of the existing interactive notification support on iOS. If your iOS app supports notifications, Apple Watch displays those notifications at appropriate times. When one of your app’s local or remote notifications arrives on the user’s iPhone, iOS decides whether to display that notification on the iPhone or on the Apple Watch.
2. Not directly.  You couldn't open a connection to the watch from a client on your Mac.  You could initiate a connection from your watch or phone to a service, and the service could return a response.

For more information on notifications, see the [WatchKit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html).